# Invalid conversion from int to SDL_RendererFlip

Tags: sdl, render, flip

I'm trying to flip an image both horizontally and vertically. It doesn't seem to be working though:

```
SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, ResourceManager::GetInstance().getTexture("rpg_pack"), &wood_corner, &rect, 0, 0, SDL_FLIP_HORIZONTAL | SDL_FLIP_VERTICAL);
```

I'm running SDL, image, mixer, ttf and net.

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RendererFlip - "casts may be necessary for some compiler settings or languages (e.g. C++)", with an example of its usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SDL_RendererFlip flip = (SDL_RendererFlip)(SDL_FLIP_HORIZONTAL | SDL_FLIP_VERTICAL); 

SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, ResourceManager::GetInstance().getTexture("rpg_pack"), &wood_corner, &rect, 0, 0, flip);
```